# Help with my MinMax Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, implementation, minmax

I've been trying to implement a minMax Algorithm (will try alphabeta pruning later) for a simple game....I've seen many pseudo codes and tutorials but i just can't get it to work...

A little help will be appreciated :)

Here are the relevant classes...(removed implementation for clarity)

```
class Board { //Stores board state, Immutable

    Board playMove(Move m); //generates new Board after playing "Move m"

    List<Move> nextMoves(Move m); // generates all possible moves, previous move is required to decide the validity of the next moves

    boolean isTerminal(); //board at terminal state?
}


class Move { //stores positions played and score gained from that move

}
```

And here is my Min-Max Implementation...Can someone please point out what i'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
private Move bestMove = null; // field variable

private int maxMove(Board board, Move prevMove, int myScore, int oppnScore) {
    out("maxMove " + board );
    if(board.isTerminal()) {
        return myScore - oppnScore;
    }
    int mx = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(Move nxtMove: board.nextMoves(prevMove)) {
        int k = minMove(board.playMove(nxtMove),
                        nxtMove,
                        myScore + nxtMove.score,
                        oppnScore);
        if(k > mx) {
            mx = k;
            bestMove = nxtMove;
        }
    }
    return mx;
}

private int minMove(Board board, Move prevMove, int myScore, int oppnScore) {
    if(board.isTerminal()) {
        return myScore - oppnScore;
    }
    out("minMove " + board );
    int mn = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(Move nxtMove: board.nextMoves(prevMove)) {
        int k = maxMove(board.playMove(nxtMove),
                        nxtMove,
                        myScore,
                        oppnScore + nxtMove.score);
        if(k < mn) {
            mn = k;
            bestMove = nxtMove;
        }
    }
    return mn;
}
```

EDIT: A brief description of the game is as follows, you have a certain number of coins of different denominations before you. You and another player take turns removing a single coin from eithor side (left or right). The denomination of the coin denotes the points you score for that move. Certain coins have special meaning, say Picking X means you'll skip a turn, or Y means you'll get one more turn. Your objective is to score more points than your opponent.

Comment: Maybe telling us a little bit about the rules of the game would help.

Comment: what is the object of the game? Score as many points as possible? Score more points than the opponent?

Comment: @MAK, Score More points than the opponent.

Answer (score 0):

I saw only one mistake: you didn't remember which turn you choose for given board state so you calculate it many times and algorithm becomes slow. Or speed is not your problem?

Comment: Speed isn't the problem. It's Incorrect, it picks the wrong (as in non-optimal) moves (sometimes invalid moves).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand the game rules clearly, but it looks like your terminal condition is not quite right.

You are returning the difference in scores between the players. This means that one player wants to maximize this value (biggest difference with opponent) while the other wants to minimize this (he tries to have the closest possible score as the opponent). this really does not look like what any real game would have as its goal.

I think what you want is that the player with the highest score wins. Thus you can just check if myScore>oppScore and return 1,0 and -1 accordingly. This means the first player wants to maximize the return (i.e. he tries to make it 1 - he wins) while the opponent tries to minimize the return (i.e. he wins if it is -1). failing a win, they will rather go for 0 (a draw).

Also, why do you need `prevMove` to generate the next move? Doesn't `board` have all the information about the current state of the game (i.e. the coins left)?

Comment: I need `prevMove` because, if the previous move removed a `X` Coin, it implies i need to pick 2 coins not just one. Otherwise i just pick one coin.

Comment: @st0le: I see. I would have kept it as a flag within `board`, but I guess keeping `prevMove` also works.

Comment: @MAK, your observation seems correct, i'll try it out and report.

Comment: @MAK, nope, the problem seems to be in the assignment of `bestMove` It's picking a move that's 3-4 steps ahead of the current state.

Comment: @st0le: have you changed your terminal check to return -1,0,+1?

Comment: @MAK, yep, the return statement looks like this `return myScore == oppnScore ? 0 : myScore  < oppnScore? -1 : 1;` Do you know any easy Minmax implementation i can refer? Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: @st0le: When you call `board.playMove` does it also modify the current board? In that case repeatedly calling it might take you several moves ahead inadvertently. The wikipedia article on Minimax is pretty good, but you have probably read that already. You can also refer to the relevant chapter in "Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach" by Russell & Norvig.

Comment: @Mak, nope, `Board` is Immutable. Doesn't change once initialized.